# Kids addressing older people

Tags: word-usage

I'm translating a text I wrote in Portuguese (I'm Brazilian) and I'd like some help.

In my story, a boy around 13 years old is at the school and encounters a janitress, a woman in her late forties. She complains about the fact of him being until late in the school, then he answers her. My question is: what would be the most "natural" word he'd use to refer to her? I thought about using "Ms" or "lady", but I'm in doubt. In Portuguese, for example, he'd use "tia", which means "aunt", but it's also an informal way children/young teenagers call older unknown women. I'd like to have my translation to be as accurate as possible, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps [Ma'am](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ma%27am) ?

Comment: In the UK, any female member of staff is likely to be addressed as "Miss" (regardless of marital status).

Comment: 'janitress' is a neologism. In the US, 'janitor' has been falling out of use for quite a while being replaced by 'custodian'. The female gendered word corresponding to 'janitor' in that age would be 'cleaning lady' or 'washer woman' or 'maid' (the latter two very dated) but the duties of each are slightly different and very different from a janitor.

Comment: Well I was just going to write the same, but I have noticed that the word is especially popular in India. No idea why ?!?

Comment: American's do not use the word "janitress". If the janitor is a woman, we still call her a "janitor" (or more likely, "custodian"). For almost all professions separate terms for male and female are considered horribly politically incorrect. Various organizations go to great lengths to come up with gender-neutral names for occupations, like "flight attendant" to replace "steward/stewardess", "server" to replace "waiter/waitress", etc. I have fond memories of seeing a long list of non-sexist occupational titles put out by a government agency -- the Manpower Administration.

Comment: As long as nobody calls me *granny* (I'm in my late 40s) I'm happy with *Miss*, *Miss Mari-Lou*, *Ma'am*, *Mrs [last name]* and even *Mari-Lou*. :)

Comment: In the US, if the kid was raised in "polite society", it would be "ma'am".  If raised in, perhaps, a rural environment he might reply (unsure of an appropriate spelling) "Yes-um" or "No-um" (for "Yes ma'am" and "No ma'am").  And other variations, based on the local argot.

Comment: The question and its answers appear to assume a term of address would be used.  I suspect that in more cases than not, no such term would be used in the interaction.  Ie, the question is moot.

Comment: @Mitch - There are some places where those two job titles are used interchangeably, but others where there may be a subtle distinction: janitorial duties revolve around cleaning, while custodial duties are broader, including things like maintaining the building's heating system and doing general repairs.

Comment: [Episode 3 of UK documentary series "Educating the East End"](http://www.channel4.com/programmes/educating-the-east-end/on-demand/57812-003) shows how children in a real-world London school interact with the cleaning supervisor, Lloyd, who has a role fairly close to that of janitor. (He's also the father of one of the children at the school, so for your purposes you should ignore his interactions with his son).

Comment: Is the translated story set in Brazil (or other Portuguese-speaking country), or US, UK, unspecified, ...? Are you translating into British English, American English, or as-near-as-International English-as-can-be? If the story is in Brazil, it might make sense to use *tia*, untranslated, as the form of address.

Comment: Following up on Tim S.'s comment, if you are trying to translate this story into a culture different from the story's original culture you will need to worry about a lot more than differences in terms of address. As he says, to retain its original "flavor" you'll need to provide clues such as "tia" to prepare the reader for other less linguistic cultural difference, while to adapt it to a new culture you may need to alter many parts of the story to confirm or challenge the patterns of belief and behavior of that culture.

Comment: Well, I'd to make some kind of "adaptation" to the American culture, actually. But I've been thinking: in Brazil, we don't have to be strictly formal when addressing school staff, generally they don't care about children's slang, as long as it isn't offensive. I think the same doesn't apply to US schools... Am I right?

Answer (score 11):

In UK schools, female staff of any role (and any marital status) are universally addressed as "Miss". Just that; nothing else. It would definitely be wrong to add the first name ("Miss Daisy") as that's too familiar, and "Ma'am" or "Madam" would be seen as insolent because it's too formal.

"Miss" the equivalent of "Sir", the generic mode of address for male staff. "Miss" is akin to "Ma'am" in the Forces, where "Sir" would be used for male superiors.

When **referring** to staff rather than **addressing** them, the full name is usually used. "I gave my homework to Mr Jones."

A *janitor* is known as a ***caretaker***.

Comment: Doesn't "Miss" imply that the woman is not married? Or is it that the word *pronounced* as "Miss" is actually "Ms" in written form? (= neither "Mrs" nor "Miss" - so that her martial status is not explicit)

Comment: No, it's just the word you'd use - same as 'Sir' doesn't imply a knighthood!

Comment: So there isn't some form of children's slang to refer to staff, right?

Answer (score 6):

If the boy knows the woman's name, it would be appropriate to address her saying it.  **Miss Taylor**, for instance.  If he doesn't know the woman's name, as I presume to be the case, **"Ma'am"** or **"Miss"** (even if she is married) would suffice.

Comment: In the US, 'miss' as a title might be used in the South, but everywhere else it is 'ms.' (and 'madam' never). As a vocative, the preferred term is 'ma'am', or just plain 'excuse me' to get their attention.

Comment: @Mitch Hmm, I've lived most of my life in New York, Ohio, and Michigan, and I don't recall ever hearing someone address a woman whose name he does not know "Ms.", as in, "Excuse me, Ms., but can you tell me where to find ..." People sometimes use "Ms." with a name, like "Hello, Ms. Brown ...", but not as a stand alone. It's always "ma'am" or "miss", usually "ma'am" for an older woman and "miss" for a younger one. Maybe that's a regionalism; not sure where you're from. Agree that "madam" is archaic, maybe possibly appropriate if you want to be very formal.

Comment: @Jay: I agree and that's not in disagreement with what I said. By 'title', I meant When you refer to someone in the third person as in "Ms Taylor just arrived". A 'vocative' is when you call out to them personally: "Miss, you dropped your letter". I agree, one never says 'Ms., you dropped your letter". 'Ms.' is only used with a name following.

Comment: @mitch, Oh, sorry, misunderstood what you were trying to say. Just as well, though, maybe other readers would misunderstand as well and the clarification might be helpful!

Comment: Madam is almost never used, at least in the US (except in its secondary sense of the owner of a house of prostitution).  It is never used informally, and most children will never even have heard it.  The form of the word in common usage is the contracted form, "ma'am," and even that is becoming rare (except in the South, where politeness from children is more rigorously enforced).

Comment: @Mitch - Growing up in Ohio and Pennsylvania, I was always taught "Miss," "Ms.," and "Mrs." as a title. "Mrs." for a married woman, "Miss" for an unmarried woman or girl, and "Ms." if the woman's marital status is unknown or you don't want to use either of the other two for whatever reason.

Comment: @Shauna That is how I grew up, too, but I hear the trend is towards 'Ms.' as the title of default (or to avoid titles altogether).

Comment: @mitch In some circles, Ms is the default title. In other circles it's shunned. Use of this title has heavy social and political implications.

Answer (score 5):

If the child knows the woman's name, he will typically call her "Miss Brown" or "Mrs. Brown" or "Ms. Brown", depending on her preference. (Assuming her name is "Brown", of course.) As someone noted earlier, in some contexts, where she wants to be less formal, he may call her "Aunt Sally". If he doesn't know her name, he will call her "miss" or "ma'am".

Comment: I have never met anyone who addresses a non-relative as "Aunt <Name>."

Comment: @anorton, there are other English-speakers that you haven't met who do use the word in that way: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aunt "*informal* An unrelated adult female friend, especially of a child." - but probably not about a school janitor, unless they know her out-of-school.

Comment: @AE Hm... one learns something new every day.  :o  (That really does surprise me, though)

Comment: @anorton, it might be regional. Here in London (UK) it's used by some families for *very* close friends of the family, as a term of affection, while other families wouldn't use it at all. I don't know whether it's used in the US.

Comment: It's common in my (black, US) family to use "Aunt" or "Uncle" for close friends of the child's parents, but that's more a reflection of *fictive kinship* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictive_kinship) than a generic form of address.  I wouldn't call someone "Uncle Joe" unless he actually had some sort of avuncular role.

Comment: @ae I live in the U.S. When I was a boy in the 1960s and 70s, I routinely addressed friends of my parents as "Uncle Joe", "Aunt Corinne", etc. I believe this was fairly common at the time. I have heard this usage more recently but I can't say how common it is. Note I am talking about addressing close family friends. As you say, I have never heard someone call a school janitor, a store clerk, etc, "Aunt <X>".

Comment: When I was a kid, the janitor lady at my elementary school was named "Mrs. Brown"... wierd coincidence. We referred to her as "Mrs." and regarded her as if she was a teacher. An interesting note to contradict part of this answer: one of the students in my class was actually her niece, but the girl still addressed her as Mrs. Brown, not Aunt, while at school. And to make it perhaps more interesting (WRT Chris Sunami's comment), they were a black American family. Looks like my coincidence quota for the day is met handily here!

Comment: @anorton I'm in the US, and refer to a family friend as "Uncle Leo." .....but that's the only time I've seen it used. ;-)

Comment: It would be rare in UK or US to use Aunt to refer to someone you don't know, I suppose. However, it is common to do so in Singapore, to call, for example, a shopkeeper or janitor "Auntie" or "Uncle". (Of course, it is inappropriate to do so in more formal environment).

Comment: @anorton, in the Philippines, that is a custom. We refer to older men and women as 'tiyo' and 'tiya' ("uncle" and "aunt") to a certain level of closeness.

Comment: @talmu If a child's teacher was also a family friend, I wouldn't be surprised to hear a child call her "Aunt Sally" at home but "Mrs Brown" at school. Just like, if I was in an environment where people routinely referred to each other by last name, I wouldn't break the pattern at the office for someone who happened to be a personal friend. Like, if I was introducing speakers at a convention, I wouldn't say, "The speakers today will be Mr Brown, Dr Miller, Bob, and Mrs Hoover." That would just be weird. Etc.

Answer (score 5):

If you were translating someone else's text, and if the story were set in Brazil, I'd go ahead and use the term *Auntie* (a common informal variant of *aunt*). Even though it probably wouldn't be used by an American child in the same situation, it would help convey a sense of setting.  As a translator, you don't want to erase all signs of cultural difference, you just want to make the story understandable to an audience that speaks a different language.

Given this is your own story, the question is whether you are trying to depict an American (or British) child or a Brazilian one.  The word choice is more a matter of culture than of meaning in this case.

If you are depicting an American child, @Jay's answer is generally the correct one.  As a side note, however: there are many different cultures represented in the US, and a large and growing US population from Central and South America.  It's probable that there are places in the US where both *tia* or *Auntie* would be commonly used and understood, even by English-speaking children.

Comment: I wonder if using the word auntie would confuse the reader, at least where I am from (the south of England), if he called her aunt or auntie I would assume that she was indeed his actual biological aunt. This may differ in other regions however. I am interested if the figurative use of aunt is more common in other English speaking countries as I have not heard it here.

Comment: Maybe just leaving *tia* (no capital letter!) is a better solution. People can always look up the term, but from its context it should be clear that it is an affectionate term.

Comment: Well, it is my own story and I'm trying to depict an American child. If I use "auntie" would it be clear that the child is informally addressing the woman?

Comment: @RoggerAlves If you're trying to depict an American child, I wouldn't use "auntie" unless the child is of an ethnic background where that usage might be common.

Answer (score 4):

Miss plus the lady's name would be the most likely way to address her. The answer above, " Miss Taylor" would be correct, or, if she's a younger woman, "Miss Jane" - using her first name. I volunteer with a children's group, and they call me "Miss C....".

Comment: I am uncertain from the wording whether the lady's name is actually known to the boy.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context. If he's referring to her in prose, as in not dialog, he will probably say something like "the custodian" or "the janitor." If he's trying to get her attention, he will probably not use her name, but say something more along the lines of "excuse me" or "hey." If he must talk about her to someone else, he would use "the custodian," "the janitor" or "the lady."

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Using "Uncle" or "Aunt" as an informal term of respect for an older person is indeed found in other languages (beyond just Portuguese), but not in English. :)

The term "Lady" could be appropriate as could "Ms." Which of these is more appropriate actually depends on the location of the story, as these terms have different connotations in different locations in the US.

Comment: In America, "uncle" and "aunt" are used with family friends, but not strangers. As a child I called a friend of my father "Uncle Joe", etc, but I never addressed a teacher or a clerk at the grocery store as "aunt" or uncle". "Lady" as a term of address is a deprecating term. You might say, "Hey lady, watch where you're going, you clumsy idiot!", but you WOULDN'T say, "Excuse me, lady, I have an appointment with Mr Jones." You'd say "miss" or "ma'am". Note "lady" is a polite term when not used as an address, like you can say, "I met a nice lady at the store". ...

Comment: ... Use of "lady" in a business context is becoming archaic. You rarely hear someone today say, "The ladies in the accounting department ..." or such.

Comment: @Jay I agree. I've seen people who've almost gotten run over by a careless driver say "Hey lady, watch where you're going!!" ;-)